# German characters not display using print_r( )

Tags: php

German characters are not displaying when using `print_r( $data->sheets[0]['cells'] );`  and I used UTF-8 but it does not work. **eg.:** "Stra�e, Wedemarkstra�e".

Comment: Yes
In cakePHP
<?php echo $this->Html->charset(); ?>

Answer (score 3):

Depending on where you get the $data from, you propably have to set another charset. Either in your database, or save the .php script itself in utf-8. This also has to line up with the charset in your browser.

If that still doesnt work, check out `mb_convert_encoding` [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php).

One more thing you can do is to set the HTTP content type including a charset.

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8')
```

Comment: $data is array get from excel file.
I try header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8') but still not work.

Comment: I am assuming a .csv or .xml file, then? If nothing of what I have posted above works, try opening that file in a text editor of your choice (Notepad++, Sublime Text 2, ... ) and re-save it with utf-8 character encoding. Windows mostly uses ASCII for textfiles.